# Как включить файл С в проект через Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

У меня есть тестовый проект с такой структурой, что есть папка проекта и в ней лежат следующие `.С` файлы `info.h`, `main.c` и `makefile`

Собственно сам `makefile` отвечает за сборку проекта и написан он очень просто

```
myprog1 : main.o
    gcc -g main.o -o myprog1
main.o : main.c info.h
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o
```

Есть два вопроса которые меня путают

1) Нужно ли для каждого `.C` файла иметь `.h` файл (как в c++), чтоб когда инклудишь файл указывать его хедер

2) Как включить еще один `.C` файл в проект? Скажем создал я файл `foo.c` в `CMakefile` я могу его включить вот так(если я все правильно понимаю)

```
myprog1 : main.o foo.o
    gcc -g main.o -o myprog1
main.o : main.c info.h
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o
foo.o : foo.c
    gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

Но как мне теперь указать, что я этот файл хочу использовать (допустим) в `main.c`? Если это был бы `C++` то у моего `foo.cpp` файла был бы `.h` файл который я бы инклудил бы туда где хочу использовать, но я так понял, что в `C` это работает немного по другому

Comment: Всё  у вас правильно, но только все используемые хедеры в `foo.c` надо обязательно перечислять. Например, так : `foo.o : foo.c foo.h info.h ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C в этой части все происходит точно также.

Связывание программы происходит в два этапа. На первом компилятору как раз нужны прототипы функций (те самые h-файлы), чтобы удостовериться, что такие функции вообще существуют.

На втором этапе, компоновщику уже понадобятся тела этих функций - достаточно просто перечислить ему объектные файлы, он сам все найдет.

Перечислять h-файлы в командной строке компилятора нет смысла, не делайте этого.

Comment: Не совсем понял насчет "Перечислять h-файлы в командной строке компилятора нет смысла" - это вы об этой строке из моего вопроса `main.o : main.c info.h`? Но тогда `CMakefile` не будет видеть, что `.h` файл был изменен. Или я не так вас понял?

Comment: В составе проекта - нужно. Уточните все же, у вас Makefile или CMakeLists.txt

Comment: я использую Makefile

Comment: CMake сам извлекает информацию о хедерах, перечислять их не нужно.

Comment: так где перечеслять их не нужно я так и не понял? в самом `cmake`? как в этой строчке `main.o : main.c info.h`?

Comment: Компилятору, при непосредственном вызове, хедеры не нужны.
CMake сам лазает по исходникам и их подцепляет - тоже не нужны.
Единственный случай, когда надо их цеплять - это проект в IDE, и это не ваш случай.